# NFS Mount Size change

Tags: centos, nfs

I have created a nfs mount on my centos server that is 50GB in size, is it possible to adjust the size of the mount to something like 100GB or more? If so how would i go about that?

Comment: NFS isn't a real filesystem: it makes another filesystem (or part of one) available on the network. Are you trying to resize the filesystem which hosts your NFS-shared files? And if so, what type is it?

Comment: I honestly don't remember, how do i tell?

Comment: Check your `/etc/exports` file to see what you're exporting, then, for an export of directory `/foo/bar`, say `df -T /foo/bar` and check the first two columns for the device name and filesystem type. The device name also impacts how (and whether or not you *can*) resize a filesystem.

Comment: Says 'dev/mapper/vg_test-lv_root
              ext4    51606140   1249440  47735260   3% /'